# Sum of squared digits returns incorrect result

Tags: function-construction, number-theory, digits

For the sake of practicing writing code, I've given myself an exercise in writing a script that checks whether a given positive integer is [happy](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HappyNumber.html), i.e. take the digits of a number, square them, and add them together. If the sum is `1`, then the integer is happy; otherwise, continue this process with the new sum.

While checking to make sure the first step is carried out correctly, I run into a problem. Clearly, `n = 1` is happy, yet determining this with a defined function gives the wrong conclusion:

```
 In[1]:= ssd[x_] = Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2];
         (* ssd = Sum of Squared Digits *)
         ssd[1]
         Total[IntegerDigits[1]^2]

Out[2]:= {3}

Out[3]:= 1
```

This also happens for other integers larger than `1`.

```
 In[4]:= Table[ssd[x], {x, 1, 9}] // Flatten
         Table[Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2], {x, 1, 9}]

Out[4]:= {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

Out[5]:= {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81}
```

Is there a bug here, or am I doing something wrong? (I'm using `10.4.1` for Windows, if that makes any difference.)

Comment: use `:=` (SetDelayed) instead of `=` (Set) when you define `ssd`; i.e., try `ssd[x_] := Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2]`

Comment: to see why you are getting `{3}` inspect the output of  `Trace[Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2] /. x -> 1 ]`

Comment: Huh, any idea where that `2` is coming from?

Comment: using `FullForm[IntegerDigits[x]^2] ` we see that FullForm of `IntegerDigits[x]^2` is `Power[IntegerDigits[x], 2]`.  Then, since _Total works with any head:_, ie,.`Total[foo[a, b, c]]` is `a+b+c`, `Total[Power[IntegerDigits[x], 2]]` gives `2+IntegerDigits[x]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The fix:** use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` when defining `ssd`:

```
 ssd2[x_] := Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2]
 ssd2[1]
```

> 1

**Why does `ssd[1]` give`{3}`?**

For

```
ssd[x_] = Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2];
```

To see how `{3}` is obtained use `Trace`

```
ssd[1] // Trace
```

> {ssd[1], 2 + IntegerDigits[1], {IntegerDigits[1], {1}}, 2+{1}, {3}}

As you see `ssd[1]` is stored as `2 + IntegerDigits[1]`, More generally, with a symbolic input:

```
ssd[z]
```

> 2 + IntegerDigits[z]

This is because (see [SetDelayed >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) )

> *The right side of an immediate definition is evaluated when the definition is made*

**How does `Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2]` become `2 + IntegerDigits[x]`?**

Inspecting the `FullForm`s of  subexpressions on the rhs of your definition:

```
IntegerDigits[x]^2 // FullForm
```

> Power[IntegerDigits[x], 2]

and

```
Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2] // FullForm
```

> Plus[2, IntegerDigits[x]]

The reason for this is because (see [Total >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html)):

> *Total[list]* is equivalent to *Apply[Plus,list]*

That is, `Total[expr]` replaces the head of `expr` with `Plus`. Hence

```
Total[foo[a, b, c]]
```

> a + b + c

and

```
Total[Power[a, b]]
```

> a + b

Thus,

```
Total[Power[IntegerDigits[x], 2]]
```

> 2 + IntegerDigits[x]